# Expected number of tails before the third head

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a question that I am currently modeling on coin tosses. Suppose, a number of coin tosses are done with $p = 1/4$ such that I have a string of tails, then one head, then a string of tails, then another head, and a string of tails and then a third head and so on. Something like TTTTHTTTTHTTTH. I have to find the expected number of tails that occur before the third head. If I consider all the subsequences of TTTTH as random variables $X1, X2, X3$ with the same mean and distribution, then could I do something like $n*E(Xi) = n/p$  where $n = 3 $ to get the expected number of tails before the first head? Is this a good way to approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is good. You are letting $X_1$ be the number of tails before the first head, and $X_2$ the number of tails between the first head and the second head, and so on.

We want $E(X_1+\cdots+X_n)$, which by the linearity of expectation is $E(X_1)+\cdots+E(X_n)$.

We have $E(X_i)=\frac{1}{p}-1$, where $p$ is the probability of
 head.
Thus the expected number of tails before the $n$-th head is $n\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)$.
.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! Did you do 1/p - 1 because the expected value tells the total number of trials (including the final success) and I need only the number of failures (tails)?

Comment: I just read up again, and the expected value gives the number of failures until the first success, so I was wondering, why did you subtract a 1 from the value?

Comment: Yes, you were quoting the mean of "the number of trials" version of the geometric distribution, and we want the mean number of failures.

Comment: Ah! thanks so much for the clarification !

Comment: There are two versions of the geometric, number if trials version, values $1,2,3\dots$, and the number of failures version, values $0,1,2,\dots$. The number of trials version is more common in introductory courses. The number of trials version has mean $\frac{1}{p}$, and therefore the number of failures version has mean $\frac{1}{p}-1$.

Comment: I just got introduced to it thanks to you, thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome.  The negative binomial distribution  also has two versions, please see Wikipedia.

Comment: I just calculated it via the negative binomial distribution as well which gives 12 but when I use the number of failures version geometric distribution it gives an expected value of 3 for each so 3*3 = 9 . Why do you think that is ?

Comment: There are two versions of the negative binomial. The **number of trials** until the $r$-th success version has mean $\frac{n}{p}$, in your case $12$. The number of failures version has mean $n\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)$.

Comment: Aha, thanks, this one has two versions too. I'll read in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would consider the [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), which illustrates, collectively, the number of failures before the third head.

You already have your probability of success, $p=\frac 14$ and $r=3$ and so, knowing that your distribution is parameterized, you go on to solve for the expected number of failures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just calculated it using the formula μ = r / P but its giving 12 as opposed to using the geometric distribution which gives 9 ((1/4 - 1) * 3), why is that ?